# Loading and executing jar file using custom ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, executable-jar, execution

I want to load and execute jar file using custom ClassLoader.

My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Main {

    private static JarClassLoader customClassLoader;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        customClassLoader = new JarClassLoader(new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL());
        customClassLoader.invokeClass(customClassLoader.getMainClassName(), new String[]{});
    }

}
```

Everything works great with simple jars but when I want execute more complicated jars, they not always work properly. For example if program is using apache logging service I will see

```
"ERROR StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogger"
```

How to get around this.

Comment: I see no argument containing a parent class loader for the custom classloader. Does it figure out the parent classloader on its own? If not I guess the custom classloader would be missing any dependencies for the loaded jar. In this case you might be missing a log4j jar.